# Why am I getting Error in data[rows, ] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r

With my code I am getting the error : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable and I'm not sure where do go from there. What do I need to change to get rid of the error?

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
rows <- sample(nrow(data))
data <- data[rows, ]
train <- rbind(data[data$Species == "setosa", ][1:40, ], data[data$Species == "versicolor", ][1:40,])

test <- rbind(data[data$Species == "setosa", ][41:50, ], data[data$Species == "versicolor", ][41:50, ])

glm.fits <- glm(Species ~ Sepal.Width + Sepal.Length + Petal.Length, data = train, family = binomial)
glm.probs <- predict(glm.fits, test, type = "response")
glm.prep <- rep("setosa", 20)
glm.prep[glm.probs > 0.5] = "versicolor"
table(glm.prep, test$Species)
```

Comment: Please don't ask similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60471710/i-am-getting-an-error-in-datarows-object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsetta

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`data(iris)` will create a variable called `iris`, not `data`, which your code seems to except.

Try `data <- iris` instead, as the `iris` dataset's already available.

If it helps, and if you're working in RStudio, try running your code line by line to see where the error happens.  When you do, you'll see the `rows` variable is set to `NULL`, which is unexpected.